# LocationManager change provider on the fly

Tags: android, locationmanager

Does LocationManager have the ability to change, from example, from GPS to a more course provider, should the device lose its GPS signal?

As far as I know it's not, but I'm not 100% sure, so I need to ask

(The reason I ask, is I'm tempted to make my own LocationManagerManager that handles these sorts of problems. I might have it accept multiple Criteria objects which are tried in some sort of order under various circumstances that the traditional LocationManager isn't flexible enough for. But I don't want to be reinventing the wheel, e.g. if Google have handled this in some method/class unknown to me).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's already available. Just google it, u  must get it. Check this function out :

`

```
public boolean testProviders() {  
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "testProviders");  
    String location_context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;  
    locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(location_context);  
    List<String> providers = locationmanager.getProviders(true);  
    for (String provider : providers) {    
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "registering provider " + provider);  
        listener = new LocationListener() {  
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {  
                // keep checking the location - until we have  
                // what we need   
                //if (!checkLoc(location)) { 
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onLocationChanged");  
                locationDetermined = checkLoc(location);   
                //}   
            }  
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { 
            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,  
                    Bundle extras) {  
            }  
        };
        locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0,  
                0, listener);  
    }
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getting updates");  
    return true;  
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of: your option is probably the best idea. Register for all the available providers and then return the best available Location value.